# Network printers cannot access after publishing website (application) locally

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, printing

Here is the sample code I used:

```
System.Management.ManagementScope objMS =
            new System.Management.ManagementScope(ManagementPath.DefaultPath);
            objMS.Connect();
            SelectQuery objQuery = new SelectQuery("SELECT * FROM Win32_Printer");
            ManagementObjectSearcher objMOS = new ManagementObjectSearcher(objMS, objQuery);
            System.Management.ManagementObjectCollection objMOC = objMOS.Get();
            foreach (ManagementObject Printers in objMOC)
            {
                if (Convert.ToBoolean(Printers["Local"]))       // LOCAL PRINTERS.
                {
                    cmbLocalPrinters.Items.Add(new ListItem(Printers["Name"].ToString()));
                }
                if (Convert.ToBoolean(Printers["Network"]))     // ALL NETWORK PRINTERS.
                {
                    cmbNetworkPrinters.Items.Add(new ListItem(Printers["Name"].ToString()));
                }
            }
```

When I run my application through Visual Studio IDE, I can see all the printers(including Network printer) using my code.But when I published this application (using Build--> Publish Websites) on my local machine (same on which I am developing my application), I get only local printers which are installed on my PC (not getting Network printer)

Comment: What happens if you compile and run your program from the cmd? Does it   show the network printers or local printers?

Comment: I did not try to run my program over cmd.

Comment: Try it. If  after running from cmd it doesn't show network printers, then the problem could be with your code.

Comment: I follow this link http://forums.asp.net/t/1292376.aspx
I have set impersonate tag in web.config file after publishing application.
 <identity impersonate="true" userName="user" password="123456"/>
using this I can use network printers but can not see reports in CrystalReportViewer.

Comment: From crystal report via print command I am able to print.Basically print command of crystal report open a pop up window and convert all the content into it.Then i can save pdf or print it throw browser print option or pdf print option and all the local and network printer are available are there. And for this i don't need to add impersonate tag in web.config file after published

Answer (score 0):

If you need to avoid "identity impersonate", you can still do it with this nifty trick. You have to add the printer on your server as a Local Printer and point the Port to the printer's IP address (or domain).

On the Windows Server 2003:

- run the "Add New Printer" wizard
- select the new printer as "Local Printer Attached to this Computer"
- when selecting the port, select the option to "Create a New Port"
- for the Type of Port, select "Local Port"
- in the "Enter Port Name" box, enter the IP address of the printer or the full domain name and printer name (Example: \\myDomain\HP LaserJet 2800xh)
- if prompted to share the printer, make sure you don't share it

That's it!

Then run your code like you normally would and, Bham! You got your Network printer available to you!

```
System.Management.ObjectQuery oquery = new System.Management.ObjectQuery("SELECT * FROM Win32_Printer");
System.Management.ManagementObjectSearcher mosearcher = new System.Management.ManagementObjectSearcher(oquery);
System.Management.ManagementObjectCollection moc = mosearcher.Get();

foreach (ManagementObject mo in moc)
{
    System.Management.PropertyDataCollection pdc = mo.Properties;
    foreach (System.Management.PropertyData pd in pdc)
    {
        if ((bool)mo["Network"])
        {
            cmbNetworkPrinters.Items.Add(mo[pd.Name].ToString());
        }
        if ((bool)mo["Local"])
        {
            cmbLocalPrinters.Items.Add(mo[pd.Name].ToString());
        }
    }
}
```